# How to put the color data in pixel in QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program which is giving me a 2D array of color data in the RGB form.

I want to create a window or something which can show me the color of pixels. I've got a Qt application having a Qlabel.

How can I perform to get color data from the file and show it on the QLabel using the functions of QLabel like QPixmap?

Can anyone suggest me to do the thing, also please provide the link for resources.

Update:
Actualy my another program is generating color data likewise an image, so I wanted a way to show that in Qt application in real time.

Comment: [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) is your friend for direct pixel manipulation.

Comment: You may just want a [`QColorDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolordialog.html).

Comment: Can you please give me the exact code with above functions? @king_nak

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't respond well to "give me da codez"; you're expected to show that you've made some attempt to solve your problem before asking the volunteers here.

Comment: I understand sir. @TobySpeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a `QImage` and then use it on a `QLabel`.

```
const size_t width  = ...
const size_t height = ...
QImage image(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

You can now use two for loops and `QImage::setPixel` to set those pixels one by one. However this is a bit slow. A better way would be converting that 2D array into a 1D array and use a proper constructor of `QImage`.

For example:

```
pixel_t **2d_array = ...
pixel_t  *array = new pixel_t[width * height * sizeof(pixel_t)];

for(size_t h = 0; h < height; ++h){
    memcpy(array + h * width, 2d_array[h], width);
}

// Create image
QImage image{array, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888};
```

Where `pixel_t` could be:

```
struct pixel_t {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};
```

Notes:

- If you use that constructor, `array`'s memory should not be freed (note that copy construction and copy assignment from a `QImage` does not duplicate its memory, so that memory should still be preserved).
- If you want to release the memory after `QImage` is constructed, you should first create an empty `QImage` and then fill it with `QImage::loadFromData`.
- For ready-only images use `QPixmap`.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Qlabel** to write a picture with size greater than 500 by 500 pixels will impair performance of your program. I suggest you to use **QImage** with direct access to pixels:

```
int height = 720;
int width = 1280;
size_t arrayIndex = 0;

QImage  image(height, width, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);

for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
        QRgb value = qRgb(your_RGB_Array[arrayIndex++], your_RGB_Array[arrayIndex++], your_RGB_Array[arrayIndex++]);
        image.setPixel(x, y, value);
    }
}
```